# Laravel 5.0: Calculation using LaravelCollective and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am an absolute beginner of Laravel framework and programming languages for web development such as jQuery and PHP.

I am having trouble writing codes for calculation. I would like to have the total of numbers in the 'direct_services_to_PWD' and 'clinical_experience_general_hours' in 'total_hours' box. When the numbers in 'direct service' and 'clinical experience' change, I need the number in 'total' to have the sum.

Does anyone know how to write code of calculation for a case like this?

English is not my first language, so if this post does not make sense to you or you need more information, please leave your comments!
Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**log_edit_form.php**

```
@foreach($logs as $log)
        <tbody>
        {!! Form::hidden('id[]', $log->id) !!}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $log->weeks }}
                {!! Form::hidden('weeks[]', $log->weeks) !!}
            </td>

            <td>{!! Form::number('direct_services_to_PWD[]', $log->direct_services_to_PWD) !!}</td>

            <td>{!! Form::number('clinical_experience_general_hours[]', $log->clinical_experience_general_hours) !!}</td>

            <td>{!! Form::number('total_hours[]', $log->total_hours) !!}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure why you're using brackets `[]` in your names, so I left them out. You can also add them if you need them.

As you've mentioned yourself, you can do this with jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="number"]').on('input', function() {
        var direct_services = $('input[name="direct_services_to_PW"]').val();
        var clinical_experience = $('input[name="clinical_experience_general_hours"]').val();

        var total = direct_services + clinical_experience;

        $('input[name="total_hours"]').val(total);
    });
});
```

I've not tested this code, so be sure to double check names for example.